# Colorbar based legend in python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the graphic below, I want to put in a legend for the calendar plot. The calendar plot was made using ax.plot(...,label='a') and drawing rectangles in a 52x7 grid (52 weeks, 7 days per week).

The legend is currently made using:

```
plt.gca().legend(loc="upper right")
```

How do I correct this legend to something more like a colorbar? Also, the colorbar should be placed at the bottom of the plot.

EDIT:
Uploaded code and data for reproducing this here:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8xgyxybev3441go/AACKDiNFBqpsP1ZttsZLqIC4a?dl=0

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a MWE? So we can understand exactly what you are doing and experiment with it?

Comment: Thanks @Bakuriu, the code is a bit long so I have uploaded it here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8xgyxybev3441go/AACKDiNFBqpsP1ZttsZLqIC4a?dl=0

Comment: this looks awesome, I would like to run the code but the data is not available via dropbox anymore. Could anyone provide the '94.DGN' dataset?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Aside - existing bugs**

The code you put on the dropbox doesn't work "out of the box".  In particular - you're trying to divide a `datetime.timedelta` by a `numpy.timedelta64` in two places and that fails.

You do your own normalisation and colour mapping (calling into `color_list` based on an `int()` conversion of your normalised value).  You subtract `1` from this and you don't need to - you already floor the value by using `int()`.  The result of doing this is that you can get an index of `-1` which means your very smallest values are incorrectly mapped to the colour for the maximum value.  This is most obvious if you plot column `'BIOM'`.

I've hacked this by adding a tiny value (`0.00001`) to the total range of the values that you divide by.  It's a hack - I'm not sure that this method of mapping is at all the best use of matplotlib, but that's a different question entirely.

#### Solution adapting your code

With those bugs fixed, and adding a last suplot below all the existing ones (i.e. replacing `3` with `4` on all your calls to `subplot2grid()`, you can do the following:

Replace your

```
plt.gca().legend(loc="upper right")
```

with

```
# plot an overall colorbar type legend
# Grab the new axes object to plot the colorbar on    
ax_colorbar = plt.subplot2grid((4,num_yrs), (3,0),rowspan=1,colspan=num_yrs)   
mappableObject = matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap = palettable.colorbrewer.sequential.BuPu_9.mpl_colormap)
mappableObject.set_array(numpy.array(df[col_name]))
col_bar = fig.colorbar(mappableObject, cax = ax_colorbar, orientation = 'horizontal', boundaries = numpy.arange(min_val,max_val,(max_val-min_val)/10))
# You can change the boundaries kwarg to either make the scale look less boxy (increase 10)
# or to get different values on the tick marks, or even omit it altogether to let
col_bar.set_label(col_name)
ax_colorbar.set_title(col_name + ' color mapping')
```

I tested this with two of your columns (`'NMN'` and `'BIOM'`) and on Python 2.7 (I assume you're using Python 2.x given the `print` statement syntax)

The finalised code that works directly with your data file is [in a gist here](https://gist.github.com/rsnape/98bbf68e333b0948192e#file-colormap_calendar-py)

#### You get

[image: Picture of output axes (NMN and BIOM)]

#### How does it work?

It creates a [`ScalarMappable`](http://matplotlib.org/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable) object that matplotlib can use to map values to colors.  It set the array to base this map on to all the values in the column you are dealing with.  It then used [`Figure.colorbar()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.colorbar) to add the colorbar - passing in the mappable object so that the labels are correct.  I've added boundaries so that the minimum value is shown explicitly - you can omit that if you want matplotlib to sort that out for itself.

**P.S.** I've set the colormap to `palettable.colorbrewer.sequential.BuPu_9.mpl_colormap`, matching your `get_colors()` function which gets these colours as a 9 member list.  I strongly recommend importing the colormap you want to use as a nice name to make the use of mpl_colors and mpl_colormap more easy to understand e.g.

```
import palettable.colorbrewer.sequential.BuPu_9 as color_scale
```

Then access it as

```
color_scale.mpl_colormap
```

That way, you can keep your code DRY and change the colors with only one change.

#### Layout (in response to comments)

The colorbar may be a little big (certainly tall) for aesthetic ideal.  There are a few possible options to do that.  I'll point you to two:

1. The "right" way to do it is probably to use a [`Gridspec`](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html)
2. You could use your existing approach, but increase the number of rows and have the colorbar still in one row, while the other elements span more rows than they do currently.

I've implemented that with 9 rows, an extra column (so that the month labels don't get lost) and the colorbar on the bottom row, spanning 2 less columns than the main figure.  I've also used `tight_layout` with `w_pad=0.0` to avoid label clashes.  You can play with this to get your exact preferred size.  [New code here.](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0798c25bc214e3b85b99#file-smaller_colorbar-py)

This gives:

[image]:

Comment: thanks @Richard! this is great. many thanks for the bug fix as well. Is there a way to reduce the height of the colorbar? I tried shrink=.5, pad=.2 but that does not seem to work...

Comment: @user308827 see update to answer- enjoy playing with theformatting :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help.  Look forward to the bounty :)

Answer (score 1):

There are functions to do this in matplotlib.colorbar.  With some specific code from your example, I could give you a better answer, but you'll use something like:

`myColorbar = matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase(myAxes, cmap=myColorMap,
                                   norm=myNorm,
                                   orientation='vertical')`

Comment: thanks, the code is a bit long so I have uploaded it here: dropbox.com/sh/8xgyxybev3441go/AACKDiNFBqpsP1ZttsZLqIC4a?dl=0